# How can I rotate a cube uniformly?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, rotation

**Background**
[Alice, Bob, and the average shadow of a cube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltLUadnCyi0)
[image]

I use the following code to simulate this experiment,

```
With[{pts = Part[Tuples[{-1, 1}/2, 3].RollPitchYawMatrix[{α, β, γ}], All, 1 ;; 2]}, 
  Table[Block[{α = RandomReal[2 Pi], β = RandomReal[2 Pi], γ = RandomReal[2 Pi]}, 
    Area@ConvexHullMesh[pts]], {10^4}]] // Mean
```

The experimental result is close to $1.44$, the actual result should be $1.5$. I think this kind of rotation is not uniform, So how do I rotate a cube uniformly?

Comment: If you have doubts about the uniformity of  `RandomReal`, why don't you focus on $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$ directly? Btw, you certainly use symmetries to improve accuracy at given computational cost. Last thing: how do you define a _uniform rotation_ in 3D?

Comment: You could integrate over a sphere (perhaps numerically if need be). So you'd only need to deal with the polar and azimuthal angles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By choosing three uniformly distributed angles for generating the rotation matrix you do not end up with a uniformly distributed rotation matrix. See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Uniform_random_rotation_matrices) link. You need to choose non-uniformly distributed angles, or generate a uniformly distributed rotation matrix with Mathematicas `CircularRealMatrixDistribution` method.

Here is a working example:

```
cubePoints = Tuples[{-1, 1}/2, 3];

areas = ParallelTable[
   randomRotationMatrix = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]];
   rotatedCubePoints = cubePoints.randomRotationMatrix;
   Area[ConvexHullMesh[rotatedCubePoints[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]], 10^4
];

areas // Mean
```

which yields a value of 1.50137 for the average area for my testrun with 10^4 samples.

Answer (score 4):

A rotation of any object can be represented by a point on the unit sphere, giving the direction of the rotation axis. And the angle of rotation.

To sample uniformly a point on the unit sphere we may use the function "SpherePoints":

```
n=5;
SeedRandom[1];
axis=SpherePoints[n]
```

And a uniform sample of rotations from 0 tp 2Pi is given by:

```
angle=RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 2 Pi}], n]
```

With samples axis and angle we may rotate the unit cube using

```
GeometricTransformation[Cube[], RotationTransform[angle, axis]
```

To apply this to our samples we use "MapThread":

```
MapThread[
 Framed[Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[Cube[], RotationTransform[#1, #2]], Axes -> True]] &, {angle, axis}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- Method-1 Similar with @Mathias or @Daniel Huber.

```
ConvexHullMesh[
     Tuples[{-1, 1}/2, 3] . 
      RotationMatrix[{#, {0, 0, 1}}][[All, 1 ;; 2]]] & /@ 
   RandomPoint[Sphere[], 10^4] // Area // Mean
```

> `1.50106`

- Method-2:

```
TransformedRegion[
     TransformedRegion[Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}], 
      RotationTransform[{#, {0, 0, 1}}]], {Indexed[#, 1], 
       Indexed[#, 2]} &] & /@ RandomPoint[Sphere[], 10^3] // 
  Area // Mean
```

> `1.50226`

- For `Ellipsoid`

```
TransformedRegion[
     TransformedRegion[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}], 
      RotationTransform[{#, {0, 0, 1}}]], {Indexed[#, 1], 
       Indexed[#, 2]} &] & /@ RandomPoint[Sphere[], 10^3] // 
  Area // Mean
```

> `12.1066`

```
Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}] // RegionBoundary // 
  DiscretizeRegion // Area
%/4
```

> `12.2103`

- Method-3: Another way is projection the cube in every direction.

```
n = 5; 
regs = 
 GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}], 
    ScalingTransform[0, Rationalize[#, 0], Rationalize[#, 0]]] & /@ 
  RandomPoint[Sphere[], n];
Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}], 
  FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[Cyan], regs, FaceForm[Yellow], Sphere[]}, 
 PlotRange -> 1.5, Boxed -> False]
regs // Area // N // Mean
```

[image]

- But to calculate the area of space polygons is too slow.

```
n=100;
TransformedRegion[Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}], 
      ScalingTransform[0, Rationalize[#, 0]]] & /@ 
    RandomPoint[Sphere[], n] // Area // N // Mean
```

> `1.50397`

- For a non-convex region,for example `Torus`.

```
n = 6;
regs = GeometricTransformation[Torus[], 
     ScalingTransform[0, Rationalize[#, 0], Rationalize[#, 0]]] & /@ 
   RandomPoint[Sphere[], n];
Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}], 
  FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[Cyan], regs, FaceForm[Yellow], Sphere[]}, 
 PlotRange -> 1.5, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
TransformedRegion[
     TransformedRegion[Torus[], 
      RotationTransform[{#, {0, 0, 1}}]], {Indexed[#, 1], 
       Indexed[#, 2]} &] & /@ RandomPoint[Sphere[], 10] // 
  Area // Mean
```

> `2.35619`

Comment: `regs = TransformedRegion[Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}], 
     ScalingTransform[0, Rationalize[#, 0], Rationalize[#, 0]]] & /@ 
   RandomPoint[Sphere[], 100];
regs // Area // Mean`